# Tensorflow C++ equivalent of data.from_generator

Tags: c++, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

My goal is to train a network that operated on image patches extracted at some locations (e.g. stereo patches with one patch at (x,y) from left image and one patch at (x+d, y) from right image), and I think the most efficient way to train is to load both images and randomly sample patches (x, y, d) in a generator, and use dataset.from_generator() to feed the training data.

However at testing time I'd like to deloy the network in C++. Is there a equivalent of from_generator() in C++?

Thank you!

Comment:  This is an “I want a pony” question and it’s too broad to give a specific technical answer, making it off-topic here on Stack Overflow. You’ll need to attempt to solve this problem and show your code so we can understand what you’re trying to do on a technical level as well as to demonstrate your commitment to solving this problem.

If you need mentoring or coaching try services like [Codementor](https://www.codementor.io), [Savvy](https://www.savvy.is), [Hackhands](https://hackhands.com), or [airpair](https://www.airpair.com).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be possible to implement this using [`Dataset.flat_map()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#flat_map), and the implementation would run entirely in C++. Using the Python API to build the graph, and assuming you have your own logic for `sample_x_y_d()` and `get_patches_from_images()`:

```
input_dataset = ...  # Dataset containing pairs of `(left_img, right_img)`

def generate_samples_fn(left_img, right_img):
  num_samples = ...

  def sample_x_y_d():
    x = ...  # Sample a value for `x`.
    y = ...  # Sample a value for `y`.
    d = ...  # Sample a value for `d`.
    return x, y, d

  def get_patches_from_images(x, y, d):
    left_patch = ...  # Slice a patch at (x, y) from `left_img`.
    right_patch = ...  # Slice a patch at (x+d, y) from `right_img`.
    return left_patch, right_patch

  return (tf.data.Dataset.range(num_samples)
          .map(lambda _: sample_x_y_d())
          .map(get_patches_from_images))

result = input_dataset.flat_map(generate_samples_fn)
```